# How to refund application fee on destination charge stripe node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Is it possible to refund a charge and avoid the stripe 2% fee? I have not found any information on if it is or not. So my solution is to offer a 90% refund. The issue that comes up is that the 'destination' account is receiving/keeping 10%. how do I make it so the 10% that isn't being refunded goes to my accounts balance to cover the application fee instead of the destination account?

this is not mentioned anywhere in there docs here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create

```
 const data = snapshot.val()
  const chargeToRefund = data.charge
  const ammount = data.refundAmmount
  const uid = context.params.uid
  return stripe.refunds.create({
    charge: chargeToRefund,
    amount : ammount,
    reverse_transfer: true,
    refund_application_fee: true ,
  }, (err, refund) => {
```

Comment: Looks like you're already doing it, `reverse_transfer` is what you use to pull the funds back from the destination account when you make the refund to help cover the cost.

Comment: It's proportional though(so what happens is that if you refund $90 of a $100 charge, 90% of whatever amount you transferred to the destination gets pulled back). If you want to recover the full transfer instead, you can do an [account debit](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits). Ultimately if you have to refund the customer 100% you can't avoid having to cover the Stripe fee, and if you are only giving customers a 90% refund there's a risk they won't be happy with that and initiate chargebacks/disputes, which would be bad.

Comment: I appreciate that input @KarlReid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is in the [refund_application_fee](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create#create_refund-refund_application_fee) parameter. Looking at your code, this is set to 'True'. This means that any application fee you are taking on the charge (before sending funds to the 'destination' account) is actually being returned to the 'destination' account when you issue a refund. To stop this from happening and retain those funds you would just need to change that parameter to 'False'.

Comment: Good answer. It really saved a day for me. Thank you.